# How can i automatically create and save a shortcode for each custom post type when user creates a new custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I have a created custom post type using this code,

```
function adsManager_custom_post_type(){

    register_post_type('adsmanager_banner',
    array(
        'labels'      => array(
            'name'          => __('Banners', 'textdomain'),
            'singular_name' => __('Banner', 'textdomain'),
        ),
            'public'      => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-admin-page',
            'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'banners' ),
            'supports'    => array( 
                'title',
                'editor',
                'short-code' 
              )
    )
);
}
add_action('init', 'adsManager_custom_post_type');
```

Now I want to automatically add a shortcode for each custom-post-type (banner) when user creates a new banner and then show the shortcode for each banner in banners screen like,
[image: Required Output]

Comment: Shortcodes should be unique, you should make a shortcode called like "banner" which accepts as an argument the ID of the banner to show. That's the cleanest way i can think of doing that. Just check what CF7 (contact form 7) does. It shows the shortcode as [contact-form-7 id="xx" title="My contact form"]

Comment: first i want to attach an hook to publish custom post type that is when user publish a custom post type i want to fire and an action and inside the function i will create and save a short code.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options if you are looking for an hook after the post is saved. They all comes from the same file which is:

```
wp-includes/post.php
```

In that file you can find this action and many more:

```
do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post, true );
```

After you hook in that you can have this:

```
add_action('save_post_mycpt','afterMyCptIsSaved');
function afterMyCptIsSaved($postId,$post,$update){
    ....
    your code
    ....
}
```